# How to check radio button is checked or not in cakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp

I have two radio buttons, I want to generate the event after clicking on radio button and check which radio button is checked in PHP controller.

My source code for radio buttons,

```
<?php
    echo '<label class="radio inline">';
    printf('<input class="radio" type="radio" name="Comments" id=radioShowAllComments" value = "all comments" checked="checked"/>');
    echo '<span class="'. ''.'">'.__('Show All Comments').'</span>';
    echo '</label>';

    echo '<label class="radio inline">';
    printf('<input class="radio" type="radio" name="Comments" id=radioOnlyMembersComments" value = "specific comments" />');
    echo '<span class="'. ''.'">'.__('Display Only Members of Comments').'</span>';
    echo '</label>';
?>
```

Comment: Why generate html like that in CakePHP? Or is the question tagged incorrectly? There's no need, and it makes code harder to read, to be echoing static strings with php instead of just having static strings in the file.

Comment: Where is your form? Let me know whether it is POST or GET.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can register a click event handler for radio button and then read value of checked radio button.

```
$(document).on("click", ".radio[name=Comments]", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the form id #myForm -

```
  $('#myForm').on('change', function() {
       alert($('input[name=Comments]:checked').val()); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On your controller you can use this

```
$optComments=$this->request['Comments'];
$somevar=($optComments=='specific comments')?yourFunction():otherFunction();
```

Or you may peroform on client side with jquery ajax

```
 <script>
     $(document).on("click", ".radio[name=Comments]", function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
    var url = "default url"; 
      if(value=='specific comments'){
    url = "some url";
    }else{
    url = "some url";
    }
    $.ajax({url:url;method'POST';data:{}success:function(data){}})
    });
</script>
```

This is sample code you might perform some outstanding functions on basis of this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using the latest version(**CakePHP3x**) for your project.

Now in your controller, use: `$this->Request->data('Comments')` [*for GET method forms, use `$this->Request->query('Comments')` instead*] to take the selected option out in the controller.

You will get more details to work on this from the official documentation [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs).